# Export a large number of data and memory overflow

Tags: java, memory, overflow

I import more than one hundred data use eclipse in the computer and no problem. But when I deploy on application server it will out of memory, and I copy the local tomcat.

what is this problem？

The date more than millions than this in another function, and just less than few field. it can export normal.

```
int totalSize = behaviorPortraitService.querySiletUserPortraitCountMonth(sietUserPortraitForm.getParams());
int pageNum = 0;
if (totalSize % 1000000 == 0) {
    pageNum = totalSize / 1000000;
}else{
    pageNum = totalSize / 1000000 + 1;
}

write.append("        year/month          IMSI                 phone number     The date of open card"
        + enter);
outSTr = response.getOutputStream(); // establish
buff = new BufferedOutputStream(outSTr);
// Loop total number of pages，Get the number of pages per page
for (int i = 1; i <= pageNum; i++) {
    // According to the number of pages to get PageResult object
    list = behaviorPortraitService.exportSiletUserPortraitMonth(sietUserPortraitForm.getParams(),i,100000);
    // circulate List collection to write
    for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
        // Recycling collection，Write data to the TXT
        write.append(list.get(j).getBegin_endtime());
        write.append("  " + list.get(j).getImsi());
        write.append("  " + list.get(j).getMsisdn());
        write.append("  "+ list.get(j).getSilencedays());
        write.append("  " + list.get(j).getStarttime()
                + enter);
    }
    // After writing a page object，empty List，wipe cache 
    list.clear();
    System.gc();
}

buff.write(write.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:839)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    com.trajectory.manager.controller.filter.SessionPrivaligeFilter.doFilter(SessionPrivaligeFilter.java:79)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)


root cause 

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    java.lang.StringCoding$StringEncoder.encode(StringCoding.java:232)
    java.lang.StringCoding.encode(StringCoding.java:272)
    java.lang.String.getBytes(String.java:946)
    com.trajectory.behaviorportrait.controller.ExportSiletUserPortraitController.writeWeekTxtWeek(ExportSiletUserPortraitController.java:209)
    com.trajectory.behaviorportrait.controller.ExportSiletUserPortraitController.handleRequestInternal(ExportSiletUserPortraitController.java:69)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    com.trajectory.manager.controller.filter.SessionPrivaligeFilter.doFilter(SessionPrivaligeFilter.java:79)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a very large String which you are converting to a very large byte[].

Instead of doing either of these I suggest writing the data progressively to the output stream. i.e. don't use `write.append` just use buf.write for binary or if you want to write text, use

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                 new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOuptutStream()), "UTF-8"));

pw.print( some text here );
pw.print( some more ext here );
pw.println( the end of the line );

pw.close(); // when finished.
```

This doesn't use much memory at all.